# limit points at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

State why the limit points at the infinity in a extended complex plane are unique.

I know that the obvious answer to this is to use equivalent definitions and then assume that it has two different limit points say L and L' and reach upto a contradiction, like how we do it for real numbers. But I dont think that fulfils the questions requirement as the question asks "state why.." and not "show that..".
Any alternative answers?

Comment: What is your definition of the extended complex plane? Certainly there are so many different ways of compactifying $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: The usual complex plane along with the point of infinity is the extended complex plane

Comment: There is a bijection between complex plane and (Riemann's) sphere deprived of its North pole through stereographic projection. Lines issued from the origin are mapped onto meridians minus the north pole. Adding this unique point justifies by taking the stereographic projection "back" to add a unique point at infinity in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sangchul Lee said, there are many compactifications of the complex plane - i.e., ways of adding extra points to the plane to serve as unbounded limit points.

- The Riemann Sphere, which you - and perhaps no one else - call the "extended complex plane", is the one-point compactification, where you add a single point $\infty$ to $\Bbb C$. As Jean Marie describes, you can use stereographic projection to map $\Bbb C$ onto the unit sphere except for one point, which then acts as $\infty$. This turns out to be very useful in complex analysis, since linear fractional transformations are convolutions of the Riemann Sphere. You can do a similar thing in the real numbers: instead of adding both $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ to each end of the reals, add a single $\infty$ that ties the two ends of the real line together into a circle. However, as this breaks the order relation on the real line, which is one of its most useful features, we generally prefer not to do this.
- In $\Bbb C$, you could instead add a separate infinity for each ray eminating from $0$. That is, you add $\{\infty_\theta \mid \theta \in [0, 2\pi)\}$. If you denote $\infty := \infty_0$, then you can define multiplication so that $\infty_\theta = \infty e^{i\theta}$. However, addition is not well-defined between these infinities. This is similar to the extended real numbers, where $\infty \cdot -\infty$ is well-defined, but $\infty + -\infty$ is not. This extension of the complex numbers forms a closed disk instead of a sphere.
- Instead of rays, we can add infinities for each line through $0$. Effectively identifying $\infty_\theta$ with $\infty_{\theta+\pi}$ in the previous extension. This extension of the complex numbers gives the projective plane.

There are in fact infinitely many variants. However, by far the most useful is the Riemann Sphere.